# Run A Function just for one Time

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, telegram-bot

How can I call and use this function just for 1 rime and after rhat kill rhe function?
Calling the function:

```
else if (msg.text == ["contact us"]) {
      const opts = {
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
          keyboard: arrangeKeyboard(locale.keyboards[msg.text].childs, 2, msg),
          resize_keyboard: true,
          one_time_keyboard: true
        })
      };
      bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Please Write your Messages:", opts);
      getmessage1();
    }
```

This is My function and I don't want run in a loop, I need to send a message and kill function.

```
var getmessage = async () => {
  // Listen for any kind of message. There are different kinds of messages.
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bot.on('message', (msg) => {
      if (!locale.keyboards[msg.text] &&
        !msg.text.includes("previous button")) {
        console.log("user message is: " + msg.text)
        const opts = {
          reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
          reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
            keyboard: arrangeKeyboardWithOut(locale.keyboards["/start"].childs, 2, msg),
            resize_keyboard: true,
            one_time_keyboard: true
          })
        };
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, ' your message recieved', opts);
      }
      resolve(true);
    });
  });
  return
}

var getmessage1 = async () => {
  await getmessage();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to listen for event just once?

Comment: I want when user clicked to contact us, and send her message, proccess finished, Because in this code first time is okey, after secend time, it can recieve message in every buttons and every menues

Comment: What exactly do you mean by kill a function? So it only executes once and if you call it again it does nothing?

Comment: I mean, when I /start my bot I can't send messages in other buttons and is okey, I just can send message in Contact us button and is okey, after again start , I can send message in all buttons, because my function activated, and is not okey, because i should receve messsage in contact us button

Comment: Try replacing `bot.on` with `bot.once`

Comment: I updated my question and added `else if` block

Comment: Wow Great,Thank you Solveddddd   @suhail-gupta

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei Great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change, `bot.on` to `bot.once`

This way, the bot object will listen to the event only once and then detached from the listener scope.

Comment: You Are the Best.